# Windsor castle 3.2 resolve performance

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

We have a big web application which is using Windsor Castle for years. The app has about 700 components registrations over 370 services. Almost all of them belong to a root, namely an entry point controller. When a web request comes, we resolve that entry controller and let it handle the request. The issue is that resolving the root component takes about 35 milliseconds. I would say it sounds quite a lot to me.

My question is if the number above sounds normal? Can anyone drop me a hint about what I could do to improve resolving time? Or to check if I'm doing anything wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: How did you measure this? Did you benchmark this while compiled in RELEASE mode and run OUTSIDE the debugger?

Comment: Yes, I used StopWatch to measure the time needed to resolve and write elapsed time to a log. In release mode and outside of the debugger for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much time it takes to resolve an object graph depends on a lot of factors, such as:

- The size of the object graph
- The registered lifestyles of components and the location of those lifestyles in the graph (obviously if the root object is a singleton, resolving is really fast)
- The amount of work you do in your constructors

So without further information there is not that much to say. However, I would say that 35 ms. is quite a lot, even for Castle Windsor. I ran a small benchmark over the 6 most used DI containers while resolving an object graph of 881 transient components and the slowest container (Ninject) took 5 ms while the fastest container (Simple Injector) took 0.01 ms (on my machine) to resolve that graph.

```
Container       |  ms.
----------------+-----
Simple Injector | 0.01
StructureMap    | 0.50
Autofac         | 0.77
Unity           | 1.04
Castle Windsor  | 3.96
Ninject         | 5.03
```

From this benchmark I would say that 35 ms. is a bit slow for resolving an object graph with that size with Castle Windsor. So make sure that [your injection constructors are simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and you do nothing more than checking for null and storing the incoming dependencies. This way you can [compose your object graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

btw, you can find a more extensive benchmark [here](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison).

Comment: Thank you :) Your answer indeed gives me some useful hints. I will verify my codebase and get back later :)

Comment: Some of our components need to create Entity Framework's object contexts. We also use child container wire up more components for every request which adds some more milliseconds. All other constructors don't look costly to me. My rough estimate is that all those heavy operations are responsible for maximum 50% of the needed time. As a result, it seems Windsor own code takes about 20ms which is still a lot.

Comment: @Thuan: If that's too much, switch to a faster container.